# updating state array delayed/not fully functioning React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, setstate

I'm attempting to write a card game, but am struggling with "discarding" used cards from the deck. initially the game will start by giving the players 2 cards each (using the handleDeal function), for some reason when this happens all the cards are still present (shown through the console.log). After being dealt their starting cards, they may request more cards (using the playerNewCard function), when they hit this function (say they got a king of hearts), nothing is shown to be discarded, but when they hit that function again (say they got an Ace of hearts) it shows the first card being discarded (the king of hearts is now discarded), but not the card they just got. The original cards they were dealt are never "discarded" though.

Since the original dealt cards are using the same function as when the player requests new cards, I feel like they should still be discarded, but they aren't. I also don't know why there is a delay in discarding after requesting a new card.

I've messed around with this for a couple days now trying different orders, different ways of deleting from state arrays, and more. I'm afraid I'm missing something simple, just because I've looked at it for so long. Hoping someone will be able to understand/solve my problem!

Below are the functions I'm working with (shortened to the main details)

here is the starting deal code:

```
const handleDeal = () => {
        playerNewCard()
        dealerNewCard()
        playerNewCard()
        dealerNewCard()
    }
```

Here is the playerNewCard function (dealerNewCard function follows the same format):

```
const playerNewCard = () => {
        if (PlayerCard1.type === '') {
            setPlayerCard1(randomCard())
        } else if (PlayerCard2.type === '') {
            setPlayerCard2(randomCard())
        } 
    }
```

Here is the randomCard function:

```
const randomCard = () => {
        let randomNum2 = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 52)

        let newCard = {}

        newCard = Deck1[randomNum2]
        setDeck1(Deck1.filter(card => card !== newCard))
        console.log(Deck1)

        return newCard
    }
```

Comment: What is your question? What specific problems have you encountered? What happens when you run your app? Are there erorrs? If so, what are they? If not, what does your app do and what do you want it to do differently instead?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would go with a different approach for the deck:

1. Like in real life, you first init an ordered deck (array of 0..51 integers in your use case).
2. Then you shuffle your deck. The easiest way is using lodash shaffle function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#shuffle
3. You now have an array of 0..51 integers, but in a random order
4. Now whenever you want to get a card from the deck, just use Array.pop(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop

Not sure it will solve your issue, but I think it's a better approach and much more closer to real life card decks.

Let me know if you still got this problem using this approach

Comment: Thanks YaNuSH, I thought of this solution after posting and it makes the code a lot cleaner and easier. And it works, so thanks for the suggestion!